# Efficient way of getting total number of lines and line index in a file

Tags: python

Here is the output of cProfile for 5 calls:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    5    3.743    0.749    3.743    0.749 {posix.waitpid}
    6    0.756    0.126    0.756    0.126 {method 'readlines' of 'file' objects}
    5    0.070    0.014    0.070    0.014 {posix.read}
    5    0.058    0.012    0.058    0.012 {posix.fork} objects}
```

I need to run the whole process for 5M times (maybe more later). Therefore, I need as much improvement as possible.

- The `posix.waitpid` is the wait time for a subprocess call (I need to wait until it is done and the output is ready). Therefore, I may not be able to improve it further.
- I need to find the index of the line `startswith('xxx')`and the total number of lines in the file. Is there any way to get those information faster than `open("yyy.txt")` or `readlines` or `with open("yyy.txt") as f:`?

Answer (score 1):

If the file is not too large to fit into memory, you can read the entire file in at once instead of a line at a time.  Then, instead of splitting the data into lines, find what you are looking for and count the newline characters to give you the line the item is on.  Get the total count by counting all the newline characters.  Here is a function to do that:

```
def find_line_fast(file_name, start):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        buf = f.read()
    found_at = -1
    # Find a line that starts with value of start.
    idx = buf.find('\n'+start)
    if idx != -1:
        # If found, count lines up to line where found.
        found_at = buf[:idx+1].count('\n') + 1
    # Return line found at, and total lines.
    return found_at, buf.count('\n')
```

Following is a benchmark comparison of the above to readline and line splitting approaches.  The above is the fastest.

```
import datetime

def find_line_readline(file_name, start):
    count = 0
    found_at = -1
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            count += 1
            if found_at == -1 and line.startswith(start):
                found_at = count
    return found_at, count


def find_line_split(file_name, start):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        buf = f.read()
    found_at = -1
    for i, line in enumerate(buf.split('\n')):
        if line.startswith(start):
            found_at = i+1
            break
    return found_at, buf.count('\n')


def find_line_fast(file_name, start):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        buf = f.read()
    found_at = -1
    idx = buf.find('\n'+start)
    if idx != -1:
        found_at = buf[:idx+1].count('\n') + 1
    return found_at, buf.count('\n')


n = 100
fname = "boggle_dict.txt"
st = "zymotic"
for fn in (find_line_readline, find_line_split, find_line_fast):
    at, count = fn(fname, st)
    print fn.__name__, 'found "%s" on line: %d of %d' % (st, at, count)
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in xrange(n):
        fn(fname, st)
    print n, '*', fn.__name__, 'took', datetime.datetime.now() - start
    print
```

OUTPUT

```
find_line_readline found "zymotic" on line: 172819 of 172823
100 * find_line_readline took 0:00:14.289262

find_line_split found "zymotic" on line: 172819 of 172823
100 * find_line_split took 0:00:12.784887

find_line_fast found "zymotic" on line: 172819 of 172823
100 * find_line_fast took 0:00:01.144335
```

Comment: Note: While it's more complex, you could also (assuming ASCII or ASCII superset encoding) use the `mmap` module to map the file in without reading it in; you're no longer dependent on having enough RAM, and you can begin processing immediately without waiting for the whole file to load (it provides a `.find` method directly).

Comment: @gammazero, thanks for your response. I just had chance to try it. In the 5 calls, I do not see time difference, probably there will be more difference when the number of calls increases. One question, I have several lines startwith(start) and want to get the index of first one. It seems this code is finding the last one, right?

Comment: I am using a vary large file (boggle dictionary) and find a line near the end of the file, and do this 100 times to show a significant time difference.  With a small file you will not see much time difference.  I checked that all functions are finding only the first occurrence.  I copied the word I was searching for to multiple location, and only the first was found.  The `_readline` does not search again after a find.  The `_split` breaks out of find loop after first find.  The `_fast` only searches up to the first find.